# Multilevel Dropdown in sidebar using HTML,CSS & JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using JS  for looping the relative array over a sub-drop-down; let's say the list is a loop element `i`.  I want to auto-generate a multilevel dropdown according to the number of time loop runs.  When I try it without a loop, it works fine, but when i try it with a loop, it shows only 2nd level drop down but not responsive when click them to further 3rd level dropdown.

HTML below

```
<div class="sidenav">
                    <button class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note left-icon"></i> Courses
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-container" id="testd">
                           <!-- this part is where the subjects would generate -->

                    </div>
                </div>


                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
                    var i;

                    for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
                        dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                            this.classList.toggle("active");
                            var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
                            if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
                                dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
                            } else {
                                dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                </script>
```

JS below

```
function testing(){

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        document.getElementById('testd').innerHTML+=`<button class="dropdown-btn"  ><i class="fa fa-sticky-note left-icon"></i>P${i}
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button> <div class="dropdown-container" id="testdd" >
      <a onclick="generateqrrr();" style="color:white;">Generate QRcode</a>
       <a onclick="studentlistrr();" style="color:white;">Student list</a>
       <a onclick="manualattendancerr();" style="color:white;">Manual Attendance</a>
     </div> 
       `
      console.log(i +'<br>')

    }       
}

testing()
```

Browser code outerHTML on inspect below

```
<button class="dropdown-btn active"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note left-icon"></i> Courses
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-container" id="testd" style="display: block;">

    <button class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note left-icon"></i>P0
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-container" id="testdd">
        <a onclick="generateqrrr();" style="color:white;">Generate QRcode</a>
        <a onclick="studentlistrr();" style="color:white;">Student list</a>
        <a onclick="manualattendancerr();" style="color:white;">Manual Attendance</a>
    </div>
    <button class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note left-icon"></i>P1
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-container" id="testdd">
        <a onclick="generateqrrr();" style="color:white;">Generate QRcode</a>
        <a onclick="studentlistrr();" style="color:white;">Student list</a>
        <a onclick="manualattendancerr();" style="color:white;">Manual Attendance</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just want to know what mistake I am doing for the outerHTML part such as below 
is not visible on sidebar.

```
<a onclick="generateqrrr();" style="color:white;">Generate QRcode</a>
<a onclick="studentlistrr();" style="color:white;">Student list</a>
<a onclick="manualattendancerr();" style="color:white;">Manual Attendance</a>
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Please Stop editing my post while removing my code and stuff .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update(after Chat):**

The *Problem* is that the Click Event for the new Buttons, are not set.

```
function testing(){
    // using here a variable, since it fast writing only once to the HTML-DOM
    var newHTML = "";
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        // I added a new css-class 'new-buttons' to better select the buttons
        newHTML +=`<button class="dropdown-btn new-buttons">
            <i class="fa fa-sticky-note left-icon"></i>P${i}<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-container" >
            <a onclick="generateqrrr();" style="color:white;">Generate QRcode</a>
            <a onclick="studentlistrr();" style="color:white;">Student list</a>
            <a onclick="manualattendancerr();" style="color:white;">Manual Attendance</a>
        </div> 
       `
    }
    // here the buttons are added to the DOM
    document.getElementById('testd').innerHTML  += newHTML;
    // Call function that binds DropDown CLick Events
    bindNewButtonsAction();
}

// Function that bind the Events, to the new buttons
function bindNewButtonsAction(){
    // here we retrieve all new-buttons
    var newButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-btn.new-buttons");

    // loop through all buttons and add the Click Event.
    for (var i = 0; i < newButtons.length; i++) {
        newButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            // this code is from original HTML, that is used for the first dropdown button
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
                dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

> This code works and should do the trick. It could be improved abit, if it is used in production.
>
> **Important:** If the loop for creating the *New Buttons* run before binding the *Button Click Event* in your orignial code (line 42), the function call `bindNewButtonsAction()` can be removed, from the `testing()` function. Since the code starting at line 42 binds the click event to all buttons with the css-class `dropdown-btn`, which includes the new Buttons also.

Comment: id='testdd'   is a extra id which i tried for testing purpose , id="testd"  is in real use as in JS file using setelementByid par  but didnt work out that way either.    if you look above the last code snipet that is the code which is not showing anything on the output screen even tho it is being generated in OutertHTML  ..

Comment: and yes stuff inside this ` <div class="dropdown-container" id="testdd" >`  should be changing but just repeat itself with the number of loops  with  1 time per loop after this ` <button class="dropdown-btn"  ><i class="fa fa-sticky-note left-icon"></i>P${i}
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>`

Comment: @MuhammadUmarKhan what exactly is the problem? because, when I use your posted code it generates buttons, and looks fine, the only thing that looks wrong is the `id` since an id should only be used once.

Comment: I will update the id part to make it clear the id part

Comment: I cant update for some reason ....  idk says some 2K reputation thing i guess,   anyways

Comment: `   <div class="dropdown-container" id="testdd">
      <a onclick="generateqrrr();" style="color:white;">Generate QRcode</a>
       <a onclick="studentlistrr();" style="color:white;">Student list</a>
       <a onclick="manualattendancerr();" style="color:white;">Manual Attendance</a>
         </div>  `   in this the id used which is "testdd" is useless . the one which I am using is "testd"  which is being mentioned in JS file as well to generate relative outerHTML ... i hope i got to clarify the issue. else with a screenshot it would have been much easier -__-

Comment: Yes, a screenshot would have been better,  if you want we can discuss here. I still have some time https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202503/multilevel-dropdown-in-sidebar

Comment: @MuhammadUmarKhan no problem, it was fun. AND thanks for your patience :D